# Receive JSON object on node server using express

Tags: java, json, node.js, express, http-post

I am sending a json object to my **node server** in java. I want to display the value in server **console.**  On server console i am getting **undefined.**  How to get the **JSON** object and parse it in nodejs using express.

**Java Code**

```
        try
            {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com:3000/");
               JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();  Log.e("data",code);
               msg.put("data", code);
               HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(msg.toString());
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   
               InputStreamReader(client.execute(post).getEntity().getContent()));
               String response = reader.readLine();
               Log.e("response", response);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { Log.e("",e.toString());
            }
```

**Node Server**

```
var express = require("express");
var http=require("http");
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post("/", function(request, response)
{


    response.send(JSON.stringify({success: true}));
    var token = request.body.data;
    console.log(token);


});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You don't appear to be attaching the `msg` or `entity` to the `post` request or `client`.

Comment: can u correct it Jonathan ??

Comment: I hv corrected it..! Anyways thanks Jonathan for pointing it..! Just after i posted my query i realized it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to attach entity to your post request.

```
 try
        {
           HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com:3000/");
           JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();  Log.e("data",code);
           msg.put("data", code);

           // modified code below
           HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(msg.toString(), ContentType.create("application/json"));
           post.setEntity(entity);

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   
           InputStreamReader(client.execute(post).getEntity().getContent()));
           String response = reader.readLine();
           Log.e("response", response);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { Log.e("",e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: yeah..! i just realized it. Anyways thanks a lot..! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This requires you to install the `body-parser` package:

```
$ npm install body-parser
```